# Symfony2 - detect if user is inside a secure firewall

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to find out if a user is inside a secure firewall.

security.yml:

```
firewalls:
    non_secure_area:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: true
    secure_area:
        pattern: ^/admin
        form_login:
            #etc.
        logout:
            #etc.
```

So I need to know if the user is inside the 'secure_area' secure part of the site.

I have used this, but of course it only tells me if somebody is 'logged in' AND on a HTTPS page. There must be a better way:

```
if( $request->isSecure() && $securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED') ) {

}
```

Comment: Remove the `non_secure_area` firewall, it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get security token and access provider key on it.

```
$token = $securityContext->getToken();
$providerKey = $token->getProviderKey(); // secured_area
```

Dont forget to check that token exist and its not an instance of `AnonymousToken`

Comment: Thanks, but personally I still don't think this is enough (of course it may not be possible in Symfony2 as it is to do more though which probably means your answer is the best there is). If the name of the 'secured_area' changed then we would have problems. Imagine creating a bundle for distribution, you couldn't be sure of what someone's app/config/security.yml firewall name would be. Is there not an option that simply returns true if the route viewing requires a user to log in?

Comment: You can check any role, for example `ROLE_USER`. If you interest in just checking that user enter password os somethins check `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY`. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#retrieving-the-user-object

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the User object I want. I would say that checking if the route is one inside a secure firewall would have nothing to do with the User object.

Comment: check `IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY`

Comment: Just pointing `getProviderKey` is not needed in the `TokenInterface`, so this is just an implementation detail in `UsernamePasswordToken`, `PreAuthenticatedToken` and `RememberMeToken`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are into something that is `ContainerAware`, you may get the `Request`, and then the URI [[see docs](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_getRequestUri)]:

```
$request = $this->container->get('request');
$uri = $request->getUri();
```

Then you can check such string against `/admin` as you wish.

Comment: Hi. Thanks, but I was hoping for a better method than that, such as one that isn't tied to the name of the secured area or URL. If I wrote code like yours above in a controller but then my app/config/security.yml ever included a different path then things would break. Maybe if it was possible to get the name and parameters of the current firewall being used (if any) I could then match the URI to the 'pattern' (as defined in the config) of that firewall.