# Symfony 2: Find matching firewall, based on route name

Tags: php, symfony

My ultimate goal is to check whether a certain route name falls within the secured area of the application.

I am thinking that to achieve that, I should parse security.yml, get the "firewalls" section and go through each firewall trying to match the path of my route name to the pattern of the "secured_area" firewall.

Being new to Symfony2, I tried digging in its source to find how it parses the security.yml itself, but I'm a bit overwhelmed by the number of classes involved in the process.

So, I'm asking for advice:

1. Is this the correct way to approach the problem or is there a more straight forward solution?
2. Any hints on how to write this?

Comment: In which point you want to know this? Is this the route of the actual request or some random route?

Comment: some random route. I will be iterating over all defined routes to find which ones belong to the secured area.

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886818/symfony2-detect-if-user-is-inside-a-secure-firewall

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I need. That question is for checking the current route of the logged in user. As I said,  I need to check a random route.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I ended up doing something along those lines:

```
    $route = $this->router->getRouteCollection()->get($routeName);
    $yamlParser = new Yaml\Parser();
    $securityConfig = $yamlParser->parse(file_get_contents($this->securityFilePath));
    foreach ($securityConfig['security']['firewalls'] as $firewallName => $definition) {
        if (isset($definition['pattern']) && preg_match('{'.$definition['pattern'].'}', $route->getPath())) {
            return $firewallName;
        }
    }
```

May not be the cleanest solution, but does the job.

Answer (score 0):

With Symfony 3 there is another way to do that which is hinted at here https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-firewall-config-class-and-profiler

By injecting the firewall map to your controller or service you can use the getFirewallConfig(Request $request) with a dummy request instansiated with the url version of your route.

Something like this:

```
    // Your controller or service
    public function __construct(
            UrlGeneratorInterface $router,
            FirewallMapInterface $firewallMap,
        ) {
            $this->router = $router;
            $this->firewallMap = $firewallMap;
        }    

    public function getFirewallId($routeName)
    {
        $fwConfig = $this->firewallMap->getFirewallConfig(
                          Request::create($this->router->generate($routeName),'GET'));
        return $fwConfig->getName();
    }
```